# Shortcut to move mouse cursor between tags in Netbeans

Tags: java, html, netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm wondering if there is a special keymap shortcut to move your mouse cursor to between the HTML tags in Netbeans to write content. It is a bit of a hassle to constantly use my touchpad. I know you can change your keymaps but so far I haven't discovered how to move your cursor between tags. Or maybe a plugin is required for that?

Comment: I have never seen a keyboard shortcut that will move the mouse pointer.

Comment: I agree with Steve H. - I don't know of any shortcuts in NetBeans to move the mouse cursor, and it's not even supported functionality. I also took a look at the plugins available for [NetBeans 9 RC1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/index.html) and didn't see anything that would help. I think you would have to create your own plugin for this.

Comment: Alright, I guess I have to make my own plugin. I know there is a shortcut to move you cursor to the end of the line but so far none of us have seen to move it between tags. Thanks anyway.